# OpenERP Magento integration Python KeyError

Tags: python, magento, odoo

I would like to ask a question about a problem that bothered me so I thought to try to ask for some help here.

I have installed OpenERP, an open source ERP software and then I installed an extension for connecting it to Magento. But when I configure it and try to connect them, I am getting and error that says:

```
"File "/opt/openerp/v7/server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 102, in __getitem__
return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: u'magento.instance'"
```

This is the function in the registry.py file:

```
def __getitem__(self, model_name):
    """ Return a model for a given name or raise KeyError if it doesn't exist."""
    return self.models[model_name]
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks